# Customer prospecting for United States within specific drive time using ArcMap and Business Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, united-states, business-analyst

I have a set of demographic variables that I want to use to identify areas within United States that meet this criteria. I have used the customer prospecting tool in Business Analyst but the issue that I have is that I want to identify those areas only within 10 min of a drive time.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to generate drive-time zones polygons within the BA, look here http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000z000000rz000000. If you want to generate your own zones (outside BA), you would need to either obtain commercial network dataset, build your own one or use an ArcGIS Online Logistics service. More about Network Analyst extension http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcGIS_Network_Analyst_extension/004700000001000000/

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I want is to find areas in the United States that have for example between 70% and 80% Hispanic with Median Income between $30,000 and $40,000 and those demographics to be valid/found only within 10 min drive time.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting the question correctly, a simple buffer would work.  The implication would be that drive times would vary for different locations.  As far as I can tell there is no map that displays travel times across the United States.  You may need to come up with your own generalized formula.  For instance you could break the US into population density (http://doc.arcgis.com/en/living-atlas/item/?itemId=cc44f12f31544b3da1e604ebae559e6c&subType=demographics) which would better represent how congested an area is and there for difficulty of travel.  Using the intersect tool you can extract the locations from the other layers, then intersect with the population density layer.  What would remain would be a map of the area with the attributes required, displaying population density.  Then by splitting the polygons by density attribute you can buffer the different population categories separately.

The actual drive time would need to be determined by you for each density.

While this would not be entirely accurate, it present a decent location for 10 minute drive time.